# mongoose update value in array of objects at elements that match a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose, schema, aggregate

I have schemas each containing an array that looks something like this:

```
path:[
    null,
    {_id: AAAAA, name: name1},
    {_id: BBBBB, name: name2},
    {_id: CCCCC, name: name3}
]
```

(the first element is always null, length is unknown and the values dont look like this)

I want to change the "name" property of every element in these arrays **if** the "_id" property is equal to a variable.

I have been unable to achieve this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use this operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc hey, Thanks that worked for me, mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I think it's answered in other question so it's not necessary to make an duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to anyone looking for the same thing:

```
 Item.updateMany({"path._id": update._id},
    { $set: { 'path.$[element].name':  update.newName} },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'element._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(update._id) }] }
 )
```